# BIG-O Proof To Solve

Tags: complexity-theory, big-o

I asked a question about Big-Oh / Big-Theta but they acquired constants in them

It is Big Oh and does not have any visible constants in it so I don't know where to start off with this since it is a sum of i^k from 1 to n.

If someone can show show me how to get started with this, it would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This one goes like this:

```
n= 1, 2,...
f(n)
    =   \sum_{i=1}^{n} i^k
    <=  \sum_{i=1}^{n} n^k
    =   n*(n^k)
    =   n^{k+1)
```

Thus

```
f(n)  \in  O(n^{k+1})
```

Comment: Reading your answer, I realize I am probably misinterpreting the question. I was thinking about the "complexity" tag: how complex is this algorithm, how many steps does it take to evaluate. You are (probably correctly) proving that the function evaluates to something on the order of n^(k+1). In other words - in the limit a discrete sum behaves a lot like its continuous counterpart (the integral of x^k is 1/(k+1) x^(k+1) ).

Comment: @Adrian Panasiuk I see what you did now following the Big-O definition but how would you figure out a value for n or c? Just testing a constant ? Can you further explain? Thank you Adrian.

Comment: @Matt I don't follow; what is `c`?

Comment: @AdrianPanasiuk constant 'c'

Comment: @Matt how do you define it?